# Extract text between elements in xml (Python)

Tags: python, xml

I would like to extract the text of the first p tag "(EU) 2016/679" between the two HT tags:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlData = """<ACT xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <TITLE>
                <TI>
                    <P>
                        <HT TYPE="UC">Regulation</HT>
                        (EU) 2016/679
                        <HT TYPE="UC">of the European Parliament and of the Council</HT>
                    </P>
                    <P>
                        of
                        <DATE ISO="20160427">27 April 2016</DATE>
                    </P>
                    <P>on the protection of natural persons with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (General Data Protection Regulation)</P>
                    <P>(Text with EEA relevance)</P>
                </TI>
            </TITLE>
            </ACT>"""


root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
```

Have tried the following with namespaces:

```
print(root.find('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}TITLE/TI/P',))
```

Without namespaces:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_2016_119_R_0001.ENG.fmx4.L_2016119EN.01000101.xml'

re_object = urlopen(url)
tree_object = etree.parse(re_object)
root = tree_object.getroot()

document_title = tree_object.xpath('TITLE/TI/P')
for title in document_title:
    print(title.text)
```

(PRINTED):

None
of
on the protection of natural persons with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (General Data Protection Regulation)
(Text with EEA relevance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `requests` to make request to the URL and fetch data. And `bs4` module with `lxml` parser as the data is in XML format.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'http://publications.europa.eu/resource/oj/JOL_2016_119_R_0001.ENG.fmx4.L_2016119EN.01000101.xml'

# GET request to fetch data from the url
resp = requests.get(url)

# Parse the data as XML using lxml parser and create a soup object
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

# Extract the data required
p_info = soup.find('title').find('p').contents

print(p_info[1].strip())
```

```
Output:

(EU) 2016/679
```